# Changing http portnumber from 8084 to 8080 in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, web-applications, netbeans-8.1

I am using tomcat for a web application but it seems that by the installation of tomcat the port number has been set to 8084 by default. I have checked the server.xml file but the connector port already seems to be 8080, while the url says: http://localhost:8084. This is how the connector information looks like in the server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now I have searched for some answers online, and it looks like it has something to do with Tomcat AutoRegistration. But how can I change this? Do I have to reinstall tomcat or is there some way to change the settings to default?

Comment: Note that you can have any number of different tomcats on your system - and also refer to another by defining `CATALINA_HOME` or `CATALINA_BASE` environment variables - you might simply be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I have checked for more instances, but could not find them. Also my project in netbeans links to the specified apache tomcat folder.

Comment: I'm not aware if netbeans uses the physical folder that you point it to for actually starting tomcat, or if it just uses it as a blueprint and configures it differently. You might want to check your netbeans configuration options - maybe it contains the reason for using 8084 - tomcat only does so if it's instructed to use that port - it doesn't use random ports (it would be pointless for a server process if you start it not knowing what port it'll answer on)

Comment: I don't know exactly my knowledge about tomcat and netbeans is not that broad. I can only find this as a possible explanation :
http://wiki.netbeans.org/TomcatAutoRegistration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your NetBeans IDE Go to `Services` tab, right click on the Tomcat server your application is using. Check the server port in the window.You can change Server port from here.

Comment: This is indeed the only location where the number 8084 appears to be. Changing it gives me another error in a xml-file. But thats an other question.